# Simplify Backbone Router for multiple optional values

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

```
App.Routers.Applications = Backbone.Router.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.view = Object.create(App.Views.Applications);
        this.view.init();
    },

    routes: {
        'search/:query/status/:status/page(/:page)': 'search_status_page',

        'search/:query/status(/:status)': 'search_status',
        'search/:query/page(/:page)': 'search_page',
        'status/:query/page(/:page)': 'status_page',

        'search(/:query)': 'search',
        'status(/:status)': 'status',
        'page(/:page)': 'page',

        '': 'index',
    },

    index: function () {
        this.view.renderPage();
    },

    search: function (query) {
        this.view.renderPage({search:query});
    },

    status: function (status) {
        this.view.renderPage({status:status});
    },

    page: function (page) {
        this.view.renderPage({page:this.toNumber(page)});
    },

    search_status: function (query, status) {
        this.view.renderPage({search:query, status:status});
    },

    search_page: function (query, page) {
        this.view.renderPage({search:query, page:this.toNumber(page)});
    },

    status_page: function (status, page) {
        this.view.renderPage({status:status, page:this.toNumber(page)});
    },

    search_status_page: function (query, status, page) {
        this.view.renderPage({search:query, status:status, page:this.toNumber(page)});
    },

    toNumber: function (page) {
        return parseInt(page, 10) || 1;
    }
});
```

Is there any way to simplify this router? It will receive the different params, search, status and page, and all of them are optional.

Firstly I'm looking at the possibility of combining all the routes into one. This could be possible with a deeper knowledge of how Backbone's router works.

Secondly possibility of combining all the methods(minus the `toNumber`) into one. This could be much easier with the `?search=aaaa&status=bbbbb` type of route.

-- And by the way I'm not using Backbone View if you are wondering about the initialize method.

Answer (score 0):

So this was the best solution I could come up with that is flexible to accept however many params. But the format of the url hash has to be like `#search=aaa&status=bbb&page=2` though and not the much nicer default format `#search/aaa/status/bbb/page/2`. But I believe the trade off was worth it.

```
App.Routers.Applications = Backbone.Router.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.view = Object.create(App.Views.Applications);
        this.view.init();
    },

    routes: {
        '(:param)': 'render'
    },

    render: function (param) {
        var options = this.getOptionsFromHash(param);
        this.view.renderPage(options);
    },

    getOptionsFromHash: function (hash) {
        if (!hash) return {};

        var options = {}, values;

        hash.split('&').forEach(function (pair) {
            values = pair.split('=');
            options[values[0]] = values[1];
        });

        return options;
    }
});
```